# Fetching data from mysql database automatically after 3 seconds with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

SELECT FROM * FROM table_name;

I want to fetch data after every 3 second automatically into a div without a click event or onchange event with ajax

please help guys

Comment: investigate setTimeout. ;)

Comment: ok but now how can i pass database result query to xmlhttp.responseText?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, JSON is your friend =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For automatically updating stuff in div, you should use Ajax along with Js timers.

Example (with jQuery):

```
var inProcess = false;//Just to make sure that the last ajax call is not in process
setTimeout( function () {
    if (inProcess) {
        return false;//Another request is active, decline timer call ...
    }
    inProcess = true;//make it burn ;)
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'info.php', //Define your script url here ...
        data: '', //Pass some data if you need to
        method: 'POST', //Makes sense only if you passing data
        success: function(answer) {
            jQuery('#mydiv').html(answer);//update your div with new content, yey ....
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        },
        error: function() {
            //unknown error occorupted
            inProcess = false;//Queue is free, guys ;)
        }
    });
}, 3000 );
```

Comment: ok thanks let me try i will reply back shortly

Comment: thats my php code i tried but data was not passed to mydiv

Comment: 1) Paste path to your php script in url parameter

Comment: 2) You got to echo results in your php script

Comment: Ok, pal :) Mark my answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

### This is my info.php

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
$sql = "select * from admin";
$result  = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row[0]."<br>";
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunction(){
var setint = setInterval(function(){
var x;
 if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        x = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
            x = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
x.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(x.readyState==4 && x.status==200){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML=x.responseText;
}
}
x.open("GET","info.php",true);
x.send();
```

},500);
                }